# Proof real root does not exist

Tags: proof-writing, roots

I have the following function

$f(z)=(z \Phi+\phi)(2\Phi^2-2\Phi+1)-z\Phi^2$

where $\phi=\phi(z)$ is the p.d.f. of a standard normal and $\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of a standard normal variable.

I want to show that this function has no real roots (unless $z\rightarrow \infty,-\infty$) which is the only case when the function converges to zero. I was trying to proove it by contradiction, assuming there is a $z$ such that:

$2\Phi^2-2\Phi+1=\frac{z\Phi^2}{z\Phi+\phi}$ and then show one can get a contradiction, but Im stucked.

The function looks like this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you show a plot of this function ? How did you get it ?

Comment: I just included a plot of the graph. The function is the result of a theoretical model in Economics,

Comment: On the plot we can see that the function is even, strictly positive and asymtptotic to zero.